# Disable clang warnings across functions

Tags: c++, clang, suppress-warnings

In clang we can ignore warnings as described [here](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#controlling-diagnostics-via-pragmas).

In my example this works fine if the code is directly enclosed in the pragmas (see `(1)`). However this doesn't work at `(2)` because the offending code is inside a function `(3)`. The warning is only ignored if I enclose the function with a pragma (commented out). If the function is inside a header I can also enclose the `#include` with a pragma.

I generally want warnings for this function but I don't want to disable them for the whole file it is used in. So is there a way to disable the warning on a per-use case?

```
#include <iostream>

// #pragma clang diagnostic push
// #pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
template <class T>
bool compare (const T lhs, const T rhs)
{
  return lhs == rhs; // (3)
}
// #pragma clang diagnostic pop

int main ()
{
  const float a = 1.1f, b = 1.1f;

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
  const bool eq1 = a == b; // (1)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
  const bool eq2 = compare (a, b); // (2)
#pragma clang diagnostic pop

  std::cout << eq1 << " " << eq2 << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Compile with `-Weverything`

Comment: I think this is actually a bug in clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is emitted for the comparison using `==`, not for the call. If you have two functions that both call `compare<float>`, and you would somehow manage to suppress the warning for the first call, there wouldn't be anything left to warn for in the second call: `compare<float>` has already been instantiated, and it's only during instantiation that anything is detected to warn about.

You should probably find a warning that can be attached to a call to `compare<float>`. A default argument effectively gets evaluated at the call site, and a quick test shows that it works well for that:

```
template <typename T>
bool compare(T a, T b, bool = decltype(a == b)()) {
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
  return a == b;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
}

// Gets a warning
void f() { compare(1.0f, 1.0f); }

// Suppress the warning here
void g() { compare(1.0f, 2.0f, false); }

// Gets another warning
void h() { compare(1.0f, 3.0f); }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could work around this by instantiating only this function:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wfloat-equal"
template <>
bool compare (const float lhs, const float rhs)
{
  return lhs == rhs;
}
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Now, all other warnings will appear, so if you do something else "wrong", it will still warn.

But like I said in the comment, it may be considered a bug in the compiler, so I would report it and see what the clang developers say.